# How to repaint paint methods in java applet?

Tags: java, swing, applet, paint, jcreator

I would like to use applet to switch between 2 "frames".

I want to use an applet to paint something and then remove it and paint something else. Is there any way to do this?

Example:

```
if(true){
    public void paint1(Graphics g) {
        g.setColor(Color.black);
        g.fillRect( 80,400, 20, 10 );
    }
}else
    public void paint2(Graphics g) {
        g.setColor(Color.green);
        g.fillRect( 50,440, 70, 60 );
    }
}
```

All attempts I've tried on this crashed the applet.

My project: Me and my friend are writing a simple code where we need to use some kind applet graphics. We made the idea to make a program where 2 characters jump up and down. problem is that we are going to have an "AI" that jumps whenever he feels like it. So a CardLayout wont work because then we are in control of everything.

Comment: Painting *something vs something else* is a very vague description so I don't really know what you need, but take a look at [CardLayout](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/card.html). It's a typical way to switch between different GUI states.

Comment: I asked a question and you answered it correctly. My fault. I have edited the question so that it brings forth what i need more precisely.

Comment: @Marc I will also suggest using CardLayout, unless you can be more specific what you want to paint in the 2 frames.

Comment: should i add that in a comment or in the question?

Comment: @Marc You can add into the question.

Comment: @Marc See if my solution solves your problem. It was written based on what you currently have. So instead of calling `repaint()` directly, you can call `draw()` which will render the graphics according to a condition set by you.

Comment: @user3437460 nice ;p

Comment: Applets are dead - [Java Plugin support deprecated](http://www.gizmodo.com.au/2016/01/rest-in-hell-java-plug-in/) and [Moving to a Plugin-Free Web](https://blogs.oracle.com/java-platform-group/entry/moving_to_a_plugin_free)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I will suggest using a **CardLayout** if you intend to "switch" between 2 drawings.

However, if you want to continue with what you currently have by drawing based on a condition, you may do something like this:

```
class DrawingSpace extends JPanel{

    private BufferedImage display;
    //Other variables, initializations, constructors not shown

    private void init(){
        display = new BufferedImage(width, height, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB);
    }

    public void draw(){
        if(whatever){    //if whatever == true
            Graphics2D g2 = display.createGraphics();
            g2.setColor(Color.BLACK);
            g2.fillRect( 80, 400, 20, 10 );
            repaint();
        }else{
            Graphics2D g2 = display.createGraphics();
            g2.setColor(Color.GREEN);
            g2.fillRect( 50, 440, 70, 60 );
            repaint();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void paintComponent(Graphics g){
        super.paintComponent(g);
        g.drawImage(display, 0, 0, width, height, null);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Well the first question is: When do you want to switch?
On a button klick? After some milliseconds?

With a button it´s pretty simple:
You just have to draw 2 panels and show the first one per default. After the button is klicked you can use the methods repaint() and revalidate() to refresh the JFrame.